# How to overwrite an icon for Nautilus with ~/.icons?

Tags: icon-themes

First, FYI This problem will improve an awesome feature in [Folder Color](http://launchpad.net/folder-color) application.

I'm trying to change the default folder icon with user privileges. I [read](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) that the `~/.icons` folder has preference over `/usr/share/icons` folder.

Then I created a custom icon into:

```
~/.icons/Humanity/places/48/folder.svg
```

and I copied the index:

```
cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/index.theme ~/.icons/Humanity/index.theme
```

and finally I reloaded the cache:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache ~/.icons/hicolor
```

But Nautilus is getting the icon from `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/48/folder.svg`, How do I know that? Because if I overwrite that icon and update the icon cache in `/usr/share/icons/Humanity`, the icon in Nautilus changes.

How could I set the global folder icon in Nautilus changing the icon in `~/.icons`? Thanks in advance!

http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html

Comment: Note  you could just copy the entire 'Humanity' to your local icons directory, rename & modify it and use it instead :) . Also if you want different colours you could use the [Humanity Colors Icon Theme](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/humanity-colors-icon-theme.html)

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, changing the directory name `48` to `48x48` is working. I don't know why that difference :O

Comment: Maybe because 48x48 denotes no. of pixels while 48 does not

Comment: Uhm, with Numix I need 48, with Humanity I need 48x48 :P